# Using specific template based on specific route param

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I would like to use a specific template if a route param is `1`, and another template if it is anything else.

However if I hardcode the 1, I lose the binding:

```
when("/edit/person/1", {

    },
    templateUrl: 'partials/proband.html',
    controller: "PersonCtrl"
}).
when("/edit/person/:person_id", {
    },
    templateUrl: 'partials/person-form.html',
    controller: "PersonCtrl"
}).
```

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: I can only recomment you to use ui-router check this docu out should explain everything you need https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
when("/edit/person/:person_id", {
},
templateUrl: 'partials/person-form.html',
controller: "PersonCtrl"
```

}).

Only use this route and specify a "if" statement in the controller. For example, you could do:

```
if ($stateParams.person_id === 1) {
    //Do something
}
```

That's basically it, or you could specify a anonymous controller on the state. Also, take a loot at the https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router documentation, it gives you a pretty good look at params. Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using one template and using ng-show for a specific input that I only wanted on edit/person/1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the best way but you can solve your issue by listening to the [`$routeChangeStart`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#$routeChangeStart) listener on `$rootScope` within `run` block:

```
.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {
    // If person_id is 1
    var person_id_1 = (next.originalPath === "/edit/person/:person_id") &&
                      next.params.person_id === '1';

    if (person_id_1) {
      // Set templateUrl
      next.templateUrl = 'partials/proband.html';
    }
  });
})
```